# How to determine singular points of the equation $(x^2 - 4)^2 y'' + (x - 2)y' + y = 0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> How do you determine singular points of the equation
>
> $$(x^2 - 4)^2y'' + (x - 2)y' + y = 0?$$

It says $x = -2$ and $x = 2$ are singular points of the equation. Do you just put whatever is in the front of $y''$ and equal it to zero and find the $x$'s and those become the singular points of the equation?

> Please show it in the simplest and easiest way. Thank you

Comment: Have you learned analytic versus singular points?

Answer (score 5):

You certainly know that in OE: $$y^{''}+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$$ the point $x=x_0$ is said to be a *regular singular point* if bpth of: $$(x-x_0)P(x),~~(x-x_0)^2Q(x)$$ are analytic at $x_0$. This means that these two functions have power series in $(x-x_0)$ with $R>0$. A singular point that is not regular is called *irregular singular point* of that ODE. Here, you have $$(x^2 - 4)^2y'' + (x - 2)y' + y = 0$$ so $$P(x)=\frac{1}{(x+2)^2(x-2)},~~Q(x)=\frac{1}{(x+2)^2(x-2)^2}$$ Now if $x=-2$ wants to be regular singular point so the factor $(x+2)$ should be of power at most $1$ in $P$ and be of power $2$ at most in $Q$ which is not right. Its power in $P$ is $2\neq 1$, so this point is an irregular one.In fact, the function $P$ has not a [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) at $x=-2$.  Do the same way for another point $x=+2$ to see that it is a regular singular point. See the plot of $P(x)$ near $x=2$ in an neighborhood.

[image]

Comment: I was reading my textbook about this and was still confused so I was searching online and found this answer, it makes so much sense now the way you explained it, specifically the explanation of what it means to be analytic, which the book seemed to assume I'd already know. (Such a useful answer, I'd upvote twice if I could. )

Comment: @Davy M Thanks for saying so. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should write the ode in the form

> $$ y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0,$$

then you look for the singularities.

**Example:**

> $$ x^2 y''+ x y'+ y=0 \implies y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+ \frac{1}{x^2}y=0 $$

which shows that the point $x=0$ is a regular singular point.

Comment: Good time Professor and :+)

Comment: @B.S.: Good time for you too. Thanks for the comment.